# Integration of TinyMCE with LWC not working properly

Tags: lightning-web-components, integration, third-party, inputrichtext

I'm currently working on incorporating TinyMCE as a LWC component into my Salesforce application. I've been following the instructions outlined in this [link](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/lwc/lwc.js_third_party_library). Also, I tested code in [Locker console](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/tools/locker-service-console) and it returns true, no warnings or errors. Here is my code:

```
// HTML code:
<template>
    <div class="tiny" id="tiny" lwc:dom="manual"></div>
</template>

// JS code:
/* global tinymce */
import { loadScript } from "lightning/platformResourceLoader";
import { LightningElement } from 'lwc';
import TINYMCE from '@salesforce/resourceUrl/tinymce';

export default class MyTinyMce extends LightningElement {
    renderedCallback() {

    Promise.all([
        loadScript(this, TINYMCE + '/tinymce.min.js')
    ])
    .then(() => {
        const div = this.template.querySelector('div.tiny');
        try {
            tinymce.init({ target: div }).then((res) => {
                    console.log('result: ' + res);
                })
                .catch((err) => {
                    console.log('error: ' + err);
                });
        } catch(e) {
            console.log('exception', e);
        }
    });
}

// and in a parent component:

...
<c-my-tiny-mce></c-my-tiny-mce>
...
```

This is the result:
[image]

Then, I thought maybe I should add some properties like this:

```
...
menubar: 'file edit insert view format table tools help',
toolbar: 'undo redo | styles | bold italic | link image'
...
```

But there is no change...

Can anyone help me? I don't know what else to try. I'm trying to avoid using iframe and Visualforce page for this.

Comment: looks like it's loading ok, but there must be some errors.  have you checked the js console?

Comment: is it must to use TinyMCE or you can use another like Quill (Salesforce lighting also use quill). Try: Make sure you enable lightning locker security from session settings.

Comment: When LWS is turned ON there is no error in console, but when it's turned OFF there is an error which says that the provided Node in appendChild is not a node, which is strange because I'm setting the target attribute correctly. I must use tiny mce, that's the requirement...

Comment: @MilaMirovic Did you manage to solve the problem you encountered? I'm having the same issue.